# Tensorboard: Efficiently display many tensorboard runs to analyse the hyperparameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow2.0

Tensorboard has recently added the ability to visualise the effect of [hyperparameters](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/hyperparameter_tuning_with_hparams):
[image]

The problem I have is that I have a huge amount of data (~80Gb of log files), which does not load quickly when I open the files in the run. It discovers all of the runs but takes a very long time to load them into the hyperparameter section. Is there a way to speed up this process (e.g. lower the number of points loaded)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to load the data eventually into tensorboard by adding the flag to the tensorboard command:

```
--samples_per_plugin=scalars=100
```

The number was just arbitrary but I imagine using like 10 would work fine if you only care about hyperparameters.

Despite doing this, it still took around 5 hours to load all of the hyperparameter data.